# 502 Bad Gateway with Nginx server hosting dotnet core project

Tags: nginx, .net-core, reverse-proxy

I can access a dotnet core app running on port 5001 locally. however i get bad gateway when accessed via public ip with reverse proxy config.

I have SSL applied to my domain and only have inbound traffic via port 443.
server_name unix.example.com

What am i missing ?

```
location  / {
                      root /var/www/html/masterwebsite/publish/;
                      proxy_http_version 1.1;
                      proxy_set_header "Connection" "";
                      proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001;
                      proxy_buffering off;
                      proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
                      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
                      proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port $server_port;
                      proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
                      proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
                      proxy_send_timeout 10080;
                      proxy_read_timeout 10080;
                      proxy_buffer_size 64k;
                      proxy_buffers 16 32k;
                      proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
                      proxy_redirect off;
                      proxy_request_buffering off;
    
                  }
            server_name _;
```

The error in error log.

> 2023/04/09 00:39:14 [error] 36703#36703: *1 upstream prematurely
> closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client:
> 86.18.44.49, server: unix.example.com, request: "GET /masterwebsite/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:5001/masterwebsite/",

Comment: Can you provide logs from the donet app?

Answer (score 1):

At first, you have make proper dotnet service file with correct dll path. Also check the dotnet runtime is supportive for the project or not.
`dotnet --info` for the dotnet details.

By default, dotnet host on the port 5000. If you are hosting multiple dotnet projects on the server, make sure you have to define the port like : `--urls=0.0.0.0:5001`.
Also check either the port is listening or not:

```
sudo lsof -i:5000
sudo lsof -i:5001
```

You can also use netstat tool too. For the first time you may need to install that:

```
sudo apt install net-tools -y
```

Then command:

```
sudo netstat -tulpen
```

Make sure to reverse proxy so that your localhost be redirected to the hosted public IP:

```
location / {
        proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:5000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }
```

Then try:

```
sudo nginx -t
sudo nginx -s reload
```

If you're working on production server, don't restart the nginx server everytime better to use reload.

```
sudo systemctl restart nginx
```

While restart the nginx with the given command,logged session will be expired. Your client or customer might have some worked and may create the issue to them.

**Restart nginx only if you make something big changes to the server.**

Answer (score 0):

I managed to figure it myself.

The clue was in the nginx log.

The URL i wanted the proxy to point to was

`http://127.0.0.1:5001`

however it was showing this in the nginx logs

`http://127.0.0.1:5001/masterwebsite/`

the additional bit `/masterwebsite/` was the problem.

and it occured due to a trailing slash missing at the end of the URL

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:5001/;`